# Responsive fixed-width image showcase without JS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create simple responsive website containing a showcase of pictures. By myself, but if there's a template, no problem. But I want to learn it anyway.

Requirements:

- **images with one width** no matter the browser width
- images **always in the middle** of the page (0 auto)
- number of columns - images changing with the browser width
- no height limitation of the image. only fixed width (+ keep aspect ratio).
- **perfect example**: [www.kristianhammerstad.com](http://www.kristianhammerstad.com) - try to resize the window, I'd like to achieve exactly this. Works also on mobile browser (shows image after image)
- I'd prefer **without JS**, only media queries - possible?

Here's what I have so far:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-smoothing: antialiased; }

body { font: normal 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 30px; color: #333; }

.left { float: left; } 
.right { float: right; }  

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after { content: " "; /* 1 */ display: table; /* 2 */ }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

hr {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  opacity: .25;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em; 
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #333;
}

h2 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em; 
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    color: #666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper { 
    width: 950px; margin: 0 auto; 
}

#name {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */

#works {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#works h2 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.3em; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #666;
    text-transform: none;
}

#work-one {
    display: block;
    width: 460px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
}

#work-two {
    display: block;
    width: 460px;
    height: 300px;
}

#work-three {
    display: block;
    width: 460px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
}

#work-four {
    display: block;
    width: 460px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

/* I am not sure about break points */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {

/* I am not sure about content here */   

}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        
        <div id="name">       
                
            <h1>IMAGES</h1>
            <h2>showcase</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="works">  

            <div class="left">
            
                <a id="work-one" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/460x500?text=Placeholder" ></a>
              
                <a id="work-two" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/460x300?text=Placeholder" ></a>
            
            </div>

            <div class="right">

                <a id="work-three" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/460x700?text=Placeholder" ></a>
              
                <a id="work-four" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/460x200?text=Placeholder" ></a>
      

            </div>          

        </div><div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to start doing it? Show some code! You can start with bootstrap... http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: What's the best service to show you my results? https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Okay, I found codepen. Here, very basic and "fixed" code: http://codepen.io/Kiks/pen/EKBKpK - always two columns, done manualy, very not smart, I realize.

Comment: have you tried this link? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @user2517200, thanks. only this could be useful http://www.kristianhammerstad.com (but images always in the middles and without "Bio text" - but what now, should I go through all their code? Looks too much, or this is the way of learning?

Comment: Hi @Kiks, have a look in this code (http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/bdgRzg)  and try to improve the way you like on the mansory.desandro.com documentation.

Comment: I saw that approach in many templates, but I need no image resizing as the browser windows gets more narrow. I don't know how to keep image size the same no matter what and use all available width with filling in as many colmns as possible.

Comment: @Kiks if you go with no resize, the layout will not be responsive, in responsive layout they are fluid and will resize depends on screensize

Comment: You might be right about terminology, thanks :)

Comment: I copied code to try one of the examples you, @user2517200, showed me - http://codepen.io/Kiks/pen/BKgzGy - but why images behave differently? There are in exact rows, not like "tetris", they don't have margins. Why? The same code. Even if I try it with all three JS files

Comment: I even tried "clean" Masonry, here http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj, but there's still this unwanted effect (empty spaces), see http://jmp.sh/kJuDbIL

Comment: Looks like disabled JS to me, or at least some errors due to them the masonry magic is not applied. Look in your console for errors.

Comment: @Seika85 thanks. probably you're right, I noticed small icon my chrome is constantly showing me: "js was blocked on this site" but in the settings everything is allowed. I'll reinstall it...

Comment: @Seika85 please, see my latest comment after your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it would recommend using a **grid system**. One common known and used would be [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).
With it you can easily set your wanted layout.

Second, to achieve this "repositioning" effect, you would need a **JS** library called **[masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**. It hooks itself in the resize event as well as initially on initialization of the dom.
There it calculates the width of the container wrapping all images and the width of the images, calculates the new positions using complex algorithms, and reposition them using the animation effect you see.

Maybe this **tutorial** (with source) will help you further: http://creative-punch.net/2014/01/full-screen-image-gallery-using-css-masonry/

Comment: Thank you @Seika85 and everyone. I'm fighting with this Bootstrap but there's still a problem. I want my images to always have fixed width (no matter the browser width - exactly like pajc.sk). But the Bootstrap Grid is resizing the images all the time. How can I achieve pajc sk or kristianhammerstad.com layout? This is that I have so far: http://codepen.io/Kiks/pen/vGoBEG - you can see I set wider container and there are manually set 4 cols. But what if I'll need only 3, 2, you know the story. Any help what I'm missing? First I'd like to set the layout, later apply masonry magic

Comment: Maybe I do not need a Bootstrap Grid for this. What do you think, @Seika85?

Comment: Look, I think I moved forward a bit http://codepen.io/Kiks/pen/NNQKXz (without usage of Bootstrap Grid)

Comment: Okay, I think this is what I wanted in my life http://codepen.io/Kiks/pen/NNQKXz Until now. Thanks everyone, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Well, images (.item) are our of the viewport when checking the website on the phone (ios). Next challenge ahead of me...

Comment: I checked your latest codepen with my phone (android) and Chrome's *device mode*, I couldn't reproduce your stated issue. All is aligned fine here. Maybe your viewport isn't set up correctly (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`)?

Comment: I progressed to the next problem with masonry (JS). If you'd have time, here's the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444559/loading-images-while-using-masonry-imageloaded Thank you.